# Hibernate ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authdata")
public class AuthData  {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email;")
    private String email;

    public AuthData() {

    }
```

This is my DAO:

```
@Override
public AuthData get() {
    return (AuthData) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("from AuthData").uniqueResult();
}
```

This will happen, if I run `get()` method:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry
>   for table "authdata0_"

What is wrong? `authdata` table exists.

Comment: What's the generated SQL?

Comment: Hibernate: select authdata0_.login as login0_, authdata0_.email; as email2_0_, authdata0_.password as password0_ from authdata authdata0_

Comment: why there is ; after email

Comment: There it is: `@Column(name = "email;")` - notice the `;` at the end? That breaks your SQL, i.e. it finishes the select query right after `authdata0_.email` and hence you have no FROM-clause in that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have got following column declaration:

```
@Column(name = "email;")
private String email;
```

This adds ';' to the SQL query effectively making it unusable. Remove the semicolon from the column name and you will be all right!